# How to go back multiple times in a directory path?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to create a full path for several folders. basically there is a batch script that is called, and these are the commands that will be used inside that script.
I did this:

```
ECHO OFF
SET currentDirectory=%~dp0
echo %currentDirectory:~0,-15%

SET ROOT = %currentDirectory:~0,-15%
SET MNIST_DIR = %currentDirectory:~0,-1%
SET DATA = %ROOT%/data/mnist
SET BUILD= %ROOT%/Build/x64/Release
SET BACKEND=lmdb
```

The output of `%~dp0` is `N:\caffe-master\examples\mnist`
so by `%currentDirectory:~0,-15%` I meant to access `N:\caffe-master\`.
However, It seems what I am doing is wrong, and the following command can not be executed!

```
"%BUILD%/convert_mnist_data.exe" %DATA%/t10k-images-idx3-ubyte %DATA%/t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte %EXAMPLES%\mnist_test_%BACKEND% --backend=%BACKEND%
```

How can I solve this problem. 
note that I also tried CD /D to no avail as well. so this is what I came up with.

Comment: `..` is a folder's parent (and `.` is the folder itself). So `c:\windows\system32\drivers\..\..` equals `c:\windows` (as does `c:\windows\system32\drivers\..\..\.\.\.\.\.`).

Comment: Remove ther spaces around the `=` sign in the `set` command lines as they become part of the variable names and values otherwise...

Comment: @aschipfl: I removed the spaces, but still %ROOT%, is empty.

Comment: @Noodles: tried that with `SET ROOT =%~dp0\..\..` and nothing happened!

Comment: No spaces on either side of the equals sign. You are setting `%root %`.

Comment: @Noodles: Thanks that was it :)

Comment: @Noodles: please post your answer as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
@echo off
SET currentDirectory=%~dp0
PUSHD %CD%
CD ..
CD ..
SET MNIST_DIR=%CD%
POPD
ECHO %MNIST_DIR%
PAUSE
```

This generates the output `N:\caffe-master\`.

EDIT: By using `PUSHD %CD%` and `POPD` at the end of the script we can ensure that we will always end up in the original directory.

Comment: Thanks. but what if I dont want to change the current directory?

Comment: You are not really changing the current directory as at the end of the script you do `popdir` jumping back to the original folder. You can also do string operations on the path as you've tried but this is quite a mess. Further, your script might become useles if the folder structure changes.

Comment: Thanks you.please reflect your good points in the last comment in your answer as well

Answer (score 1):

`..` is a folder's parent (and `.` is the folder itself). So `c:\windows\system32\drivers\..\..` equals `c:\windows` (as does `c:\windows\system32\drivers\..\..\.\.\.\.\.`).

Aso

No spaces on either side of the equals sign. You are setting `%root %`

Comment: I actually meant your last comment on root! 
what was the case that solved my problem :)